Refuting a claim that uses revelations
I would like your help in refuting a Christian claim as this has been bugging me for a while now
Is the epsilon truly more fitting of the first letter of the word "Allah" (as pronounced in Arabic) when when translated to greek from arabic or would it be an intermediate . Also wouldn't starting with epsilon render the pronunciation of the rest of the word incorrect as in Arabic the second alpha isn't really 'a' it's more of an o and the L's are pronounced differently and the xhi at the end would become silent.
I would be grateful if you could respond to this as both Christians and Muslims use this word to refer to God.
https://christianforums.net/threads/666-is-allah.102890/

this doesn't sound like a Christianity question, more of a language one. I don't know of Christians who use Allah to refer to God, but that may be a language thing

"refuting a Christian claim" — The question needs to explicitly quote that claim and indicate where it comes from.

@RayButterworth it's linked at the bottom of the post , I apologise if it wasn't explicit

You might ask in Latin Language Stack Exchange, which despite its name also answers questions about ancient Greek. ¶ If you do, I'd suggest dropping the references to Christian and Muslim, since that would be irrelevant for a question about Greek spelling.

This question is now duplicated on SE-BH. I suggest it be closed here.

I’m voting to close this question because "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"; it is about Greek spelling, not about Christianity.

I’m voting to close this question because this is missing the context as to why it is a question about Christianity specifically.

The link provided gives a page on a Christian web-site dealing with Revelation 13:18, "Here is wisdom: Let him that hath understanding count the number of the beast: for it is the number of a man; and his number is Six hundred threescore and six."
There is no way I want this answer to delve into that matter, for there are differing interpretations, but it certainly is linked to the matter raised by the OP, whether there has been a mistake, or a misunderstanding regarding the translation into Greek of the Arabic name for God.
The link lies in whether Revelation 13:18 has been mistranslated from the apostle John's vision, which he wrote down in Greek; did his vision show Arabic for 'the number of the beast', so that later copyists who were puzzled by the writing of that number, worked out a similar form of letters in Greek and put that down? And the English translation of the Greek for that number is six hundred and sixty-six. But if John saw Arabic script for that number, it would be an Arabic phrase for the Arabic character “bismillah,” which means “in the name of Allah.”
As I do not want to promote any particular interpretation of the "mark of the beast", I will not provide various links about this, although I could. This answer is simply to flag up the possibility of the misunderstanding the OP is concerned about having arisen due to whether the original manuscript of the apostle John had Greek for 666, when it was Arabic for "in the name of Allah", or not.

I get the idea of the theory, but when you have start changing spellings, it shows the derivation is not natural.
The Abjad value of الله (Allah) is indeed 66 (5+30+30+1).
This is the same numbering system that gives the value 786 (familiar to some Muslims) to the Bismillah, the first verse of the Holy Quran.
Modern (Hellenic) Greek interprets Allah Αλλάχ which has the value 662 (1+30+30+1+600).
This has no strong correlation with:
Revelation 13:18 Here is wisdom. Let him that hath understanding count the number of the beast: for it is the number of a man; and his number is Six hundred threescore and six.
Allah is not a beast, nor a man, and his number is not 666, so it seems to me there is no detailed correlation.
66 is also the number of books in the Holy Bible.
The Hebrew number of THY GOD (אלהיך) is also 66 (20+10+5+30+1) as in:
Deuteronomy 28
  58 If thou wilt not observe to do all the words of this law that are
written in this book, that thou mayest fear this glorious and fearful
name, THE LORD THY GOD;
  59 Then the LORD will make thy plagues wonderful, and the plagues of
thy seed, even great plagues, and of long continuance, and sore
sicknesses, and of long continuance.
Deuternomy 28:58-59

the professor that was cited for the greek , i think it was reverend Terence Espinoza , is he right about the way the epsilon is pronounced? Because I have come across a well established linguist in the Arabic field, marijn van putten, who said that the Arabic video that op cites (from arabic 101) is not reputable . He also mentioned that the word Allah is attested in greek transcription as alpha lambda lambda alpha . He didn't even mention the chi at the end, what do you think about this?

Nothing holy in Hebrew converted  to greek through isopsephy gives you 666?i feel theres a ton of possibilities and the op is just cherry picking

@Tahir Well, I've seen notes reproduced from the 16th century suggesting "λατεινος" (30+1+300+5+10+50+70+200=666) meaning the Latin man, and associated it with Rome. The only man mentioned directly in connection with Latin was Pontius Pilate. The PoPe is called the Pontiff until this day. But you are right, there are many possibilities, and Satanists deliberately use this number to be secretly Satanic publicly.
